# How to create duplicate bookmarks in Android?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

I'm using the stock browser on my new Samsung S3 mini (Jellybean) and am having trouble with the browser. When I go to the bookmarks page it seems to have two sections, one called "My Device" and one for my Google account, which seems to contain my bookmarks from my desktop Chrome browser.

I have 100 or so bookmarks on my desktop browser since I have a mouse and a nice big screen to go along with it but on my phone I don't expect to be able to browse more than a few very often so I'd like to create a set of bookmarks to access from the phone quickly and easily. I don't want to navigate around the complex directory structure that I have for my desktop.

I'm running into a problem though. It seems that the browser won't let you duplicate any bookmarks. When you try to add them it just says "already in use" if the bookmark exists anywhere under "My Devices" or my Google account and no matter where I'm adding the bookmark.

Have you all run into this problem and how have you solved it? Should I resort to stupid tricks like adding a "#" after all the bookmarks for the mobile version simply to convince the browser that it's a different page when it's not really?

Comment: What's the S3 mini's stock browser? The old one (known from Gingerbread, etc.) or already Google Chrome?

Comment: same as old one

Comment: Are you having better luck with Chrome?